# Index of item inside StructuredArray

Tags: geographics, index

How do I extract position of item in `StructuredArray` without converting using `Normal`?

The following code finds the position of the largest distance inside `GeoDistanceList`.

But using `Normal` makes it quite slow.

On the other hand if I use `Position[geolist, m]` instead of `Position[Normal[geolist], m]` then it returns `{}`.

```
geolist = 
 GeoDistanceList[
  Transpose[{RandomReal[{-90, 90}, 100000], 
    RandomReal[{-180, 180}, 100000]}]]
m = Max[geolist]
Position[Normal[geolist], m] // Timing
```

Comment: Do the search on the result of `ArrayRules[]`?

Comment: It is even slower than using `Normal`.

Comment: how about `Position[geolist["StructuredData"][[2]], 
  QuantityMagnitude@Max[geolist]] // Timing`  or `Position[geolist["Magnitudes"], QuantityMagnitude@Max[geolist]]//Timing`?

Comment: I wonder where did you get those strings `"StructuredData"` or `"Magnitudes"`? OK `StructuredData` can be seen inside fullform of `geolist` but how did you know about  `"Magnitudes"`?

Comment: @azerbajdzan you can check `geolist["Properties"]` - you'll get `{"Magnitudes", "UnitBlock", "Flattening", "Properties", "Structure", "StructuredData", "StructuredAlgorithms", "Summary"}`. See the documentation precisely [here](https://wolfram.com/xid/0i1u2jbp2-dn7sw)

Comment: @azerbajdzan `geolist` is not a `SparseArray`, so you should consider rephrasing the question.

Comment: Yes you are right it should be `StructuredArray`. I will correct the question... but similarly you can do the same with `SparseArray` just instead of `"Magnitudes"` you use `"NonzeroValues"` as one of `"Properties"` of `SparseArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the property `"Magnitudes"` of `geolist`

```
SeedRandom[1]
geolist = GeoDistanceList[Transpose[{RandomReal[{-90, 90}, 100000], 
     RandomReal[{-180, 180}, 100000]}]];

m = Max[geolist];

Position[Normal[geolist], m] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {2.97357, {{31237}}}
> ```

```
qm = QuantityMagnitude @ m;

Position[geolist["Magnitudes"], qm] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0310958, {{31237}}}
> ```

Faster alternatives:

```
Nearest[geolist["Magnitudes"] -> "Index"][QuantityMagnitude @ m] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.014323, {31237}}
> ```

```
Position[Unitize[geolist["Magnitudes"] - qm], 0] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0070999, {{31237}}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

[`GeoDistanceList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoDistanceList.html) returns a [`QuantityArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantityArray.html) object, which can be a tricky thing to deal with.  Quantity arrays were invented to give a compact and more performant way of dealing with lists/arrays of quantities.

For example `Max` has been overloaded to work with `QuantityArray` objects, and can return the maximum value very quickly. Compare the timing for these calls:

```
In[37]:= AbsoluteTiming[Max[geolist]]

Out[37]= {0.001061, Quantity[12413.7, "Miles"]}

In[38]:= With[{normal = Normal[geolist]},
 AbsoluteTiming[Max[normal]]
 ]

Out[38]= {1.21813, Quantity[12413.7, "Miles"]}
```

But what `QuantityArray` doesn't do is let you *see* the quantities inside very easily, unless you use `Normal` to convert it to a list of quantities.  That's why the documentation uses `Normal`, so you can see what is inside the displayed form.

But it seems that `Position` has not been overloaded to work efficiently with `QuantityArray` objects, and so it is necessary to convert it.  But rather than convert it to a list of quantities using [`Normal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html), we can just grab the magnitudes using [`QuantityMagnitude`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuantityMagnitude.html), and call both `Max` and `Position` on them quite quickly:

```
In[11]:= geolist = 
  GeoDistanceList[
   Transpose[{RandomReal[{-90, 90}, 100000], 
     RandomReal[{-180, 180}, 100000]}]];
Position[Normal[geolist], Max[geolist]] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[12]= {3.5092, {{58024}}}

In[13]:= With[{vals = QuantityMagnitude[geolist]}, 
  Position[vals, Max[vals]]] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[13]= {0.011429, {{58024}}}
```

Comment: If you look in help for `GeoDistanceList` then it is full of `Normal` being used. And there is no reference to `QuantityMagnitude` or `"Magnitudes"`. So whether `Normal` is wrong function or not I do not know... but certainly help for `GeoDistanceList` is (if not wrong) at least incomplete.